# Proxy implementation to external network approach

Tags: python, html, web-applications, proxy, iot

I'm currently working on an IOT project which requires me to proxy the localhost through a web app. The main reason why I want to use a proxy is that most of the settings of my devices are only accessible by their localhost. In the future, I want to port all the settings to the web application, however now it is taking to much time to do this.
The current techniques I'm using for this project are Vue.js for frontend purposes and python for backend purposes.

How should you implement a mechanism to render the IOT device its localhost trough the web application? Which techniques should I use for this? I've heard about UPnP but I can't find any implementation to cover this.